# Можно ли создавать классы, содержащие объекты этого же класса?

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, указатели, ссылки

Можно ли создавать классы, содержащие в качестве данных-членов объекты этого же класса, указатели/ссылки на такие объекты, их массивы?

Например:

```
class A
{
    A x;
    A* y;
    std::vector<A> v;
};
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Объекты и массивы — нет, так как на момент объявления класс ещё не создан до конца, а потому неизвестно, сколько места требуется выделить для его экземпляров.

А указатели и ссылки — пожалуйста, ведь *факт* существования данного класса уже известен.

Comment: Дополню: указатели и ссылки можно создавать даже после объявления класса в виде: `class A;`

Comment: А массивы объектов?

Comment: @flow массивы не получится создать -- размер элемента неизвестен.

Comment: @nzeemin Почему тогда `class A
{
 std::vector<A> v;
};` компилируется?

Comment: @flow Массив -- это `A arr[10]`, а std:vector<A> -- это не массив, а просто другой класс, манипулирующий экземплярами класса A.

Comment: @flow для вектора работает, потому что в потрохах он хранит указатель. А размер указателя не зависит от типа, для любых типов данных `T1` и `T2` справедливо равенство `sizeof(T1*) == sizeof(T2*)`.

Answer (score 15):

Указатели - запросто. А вот представьте себе, сколько памяти займет ваш класс, описанный в вопросе. Ведь он содержит в себе `x`, который содержит в себе `x`, который содержит в себе... Ну, вы понимаете - бесконечная рекурсия без каких бы то ни было надежд на прекращение. Это так, самое простое объяснение, почему нельзя.

Указатели же - запросто. Это очень широко применяемый метод - указатель на себя - для списков, деревьев и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

Только если этот член статический, например:

```
class A
{
    static A a;
};
```